# HSQL access from both Java and Ruby?

Tags: java, sql, ruby, database, hsqldb

Is it possible to access a local HSQL database from Ruby as well as from Java? (separately of course, not concurrent) The Ruby SQL toolkit called Sequel, for example, claims to have "adapters" for JDBC, so I think the answer is yes, yes? =)

If the answer is "kind of" or something, is there a better RDBMS that would allow straightforward access from both languages? Ideally I would want support for server-side DB's as well...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that you use the JRuby implementation of Ruby. I've used Sequel with H2 on JRuby - IIRC I just installed Sequel and the h2 gem on JRuby and then specified the database connection as normal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [rubyforge project](http://rubyforge.org/projects/hypersonic/) for an HSQLDB driver.  I haven't used it, but it looks like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ruby programmer so not sure about Ruby. But if there is a JDBC adapter for that database then you should be able to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JRuby, you can use all JDBC adapters.